# How to create constraint, based on field value

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with tariffs.

Table has three columns: id INT, reception INT, is_default INT (0/1);

I need to make constraint, which will restrict creation of new tariff for the same reception with is_default = 1. So each reception could have only one default tariff.

Comment: don't use integers for boolean flags. Use a `boolean` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a [unique partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL-EX3) for that:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniq_tariff_reception_where_is_default
  ON tariff (reception)
  WHERE is_default = 1
```

`UNIQUE` indexes work exactly the same as `UNIQUE` constraints (under the hood, `UNIQUE` constraints actually creates `UNIQUE` indexes to achieve uniqueness), but the constraint version [cannot be partial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS):

> Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns listed in the constraint. A uniqueness restriction covering only some rows cannot be written as a unique constraint, but it is possible to enforce such a restriction by creating a unique partial index.

*Notes*: please consider using the `BOOLEAN` type for the `is_default` column. With that, your index could be `WHERE is_default = TRUE` or even `WHERE is_default`.